# MonoTouch Parameter Array Length does not match the number of message body parts exception

Tags: wcf, json, https, xamarin.ios

I am writing a MonoTouch app for iPhone and i am getting the following exception when calling a WCF web service.

```
Parameter array length does not match the number of message body parts at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.WebMessageFormatter+WebClientMessageFormatter.SerializeRequest (System.ServiceModel.Channels.MessageVersion messageVersion, System.Object[] parameters) [0x0003e] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/System.ServiceModel.Web/System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher/WebMessageFormatter.cs:310 
  at System.ServiceModel.Description.WebHttpBehavior+ClientPairFormatter.SerializeRequest (System.ServiceModel.Channels.MessageVersion messageVersion, System.Object[] parameters) [0x00000] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/System.ServiceModel.Web/System.ServiceModel.Description/WebHttpBehavior.cs:142 
  at System.ServiceModel.MonoInternal.ClientRuntimeChannel.CreateRequest (System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ClientOperation op, System.Object[] parameters) [0x0001e] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/System.ServiceModel/System.ServiceModel/ClientRuntimeChannel.cs:611 
  at System.ServiceModel.MonoInternal.ClientRuntimeChannel.Request (System.ServiceModel.Description.OperationDescription od, System.Object[] parameters) [0x0002d] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/System.ServiceModel/System.ServiceModel/ClientRuntimeChannel.cs:512 
  at System.ServiceModel.MonoInternal.ClientRuntimeChannel.DoProcess (System.Reflection.MethodBase method, System.String operationName, System.Object[] parameters) [0x00038] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/System.ServiceModel/System.ServiceModel/ClientRuntimeChannel.cs:482 
  at System.ServiceModel.MonoInternal.ClientRuntimeChannel.Process (System.Reflection.MethodBase method, System.String operationName, System.Object[] parameters) [0x00000] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/System.ServiceModel/System.ServiceModel/ClientRuntimeChannel.cs:462
```

I am calling the service with the following methods (Some namespaces have been removed for readability):

```
public void Begin ()
{
    try 
    {
        WebHttpBinding bnd = new WebHttpBinding (WebHttpSecurityMode.Transport);
        bnd.MaxBufferSize=2147483647;
        bnd.MaxReceivedMessageSize=2147483647;
        EndpointAddress addr = new EndpointAddress (new Uri(this.Url));
        ServiceClient service = new ServiceClient (bnd, addr);
        service.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new WebHttpBehavior());
        Login login = new Login() 
        { 
            InstitutionId=this.InstitutionNumber.ToString ("D4"), 
            CompanyNumber = (int)this.CompanyId, 
            Password = this.Password, 
            UserName = this.Username 
        };
        LoginRequest loginRequest = new LoginRequest{} (GetClientLoginData(), login);
        service.LoginCompleted += HandleServiceLoginCompleted;
        service.LoginAsync(loginRequest);
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        if(failed != null)
        {
            failed(new ErrorInformation(e));
        }
    }
}

void HandleServiceLoginCompleted (object sender, LoginCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Cancelled)
    {
        if (failed != null)
        {
            failed (new ErrorInformation ("Request was cancelled"));
        }
    }
    else if(e.Error != null)
    {
        if (failed != null)
        {
            failed (new ErrorInformation (e.Error));
        }
    }
    else
    {
        ServiceClient service =  sender as ServiceClient;
        LoginResponse response = e.Result;
        if (response.LoginResult) 
        {
            if (success != null)
                success ();
        } 
        else 
        {
            if (failed != null)
                failed (new ErrorInformation (response.errmsg));
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this e.Error in HandleServiceLoginCompleted is not null (it is the above exception).  I ran wireshark and no packets are sent to the server at all.  The service works correctly when called by other means (such as ASP.NET web pages.)  I generated the service reference using silverlight's slsvcutil.exe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `bnd.ReaderQuotas.MaxArrayLength = int.MaxValue`
There are also some other limits that you can increase in ReaderQuotas.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I am using WebHttpBinding which (at least in MonoTouch) does not have a ReaderQuotas Property.  The BasicHttpBinding in MonoTouch does have ReaderQuotas, but if I switch to that I get binding conflicts.

Comment: UPDATE:  I just checked WebHttpBinding in VS2010 on a .NET 4.0 project and it has ReaderQuotas available.  So I think I will take this up with the MonoTouch folks as something they need to add.